# Super slow LINQ Max() function execution

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

Trying to figure out why the [LINQ Max function](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.max?view=netcore-2.2) is actually way slower than the raw SQL query.

- I am using a quite big SQLite file (300MB, 2-3 million rows).
- .NET Core and EF Core.

```
var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
// LINQ Max function. This part takes around 2300 ms
ulong max = context.Messages.Select(m => m.Id).Max();
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms - Max");

watch.Restart();
// Raw SQL. This part takes 1 ms
var max2 = context.Messages.FromSql("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) from messages)").ToList();
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms - MAX SQL");
```

Results (not on first run) :

```
2308ms - Max
1ms - MAX SQL
```

---

**EDIT** - Profiler

I turned on profiler and found out I had [this problem](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11797) with this code :

```
var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var maxId = context.Messages.Max(m => m.Id);
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms - Max ");
```

Since I have this warning :

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression 'Max()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
```

So it executes this weird SQL query :

```
SELECT "m"."Id"
FROM "Messages" AS "m",
```

Github issue above says :

> In linq/C# when you call aggregate methods like Average/Min/Max on an
>   enumerable of non-nullable type which is empty, it throws exception.

Thus I tried to fix the problem with this new code

```
var maxId = context.Messages.Max(m => (ulong?)m.Id);
```

But still got the warning. What am I missing?

---

**EDIT2** - Alternative

Quick fix/alternative for the slow Max() function, not using raw-SQL statement :

```
var message = context.Messages.OrderByDescending(m => m.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

This one does not give any warning.

Comment: What **exact** SQL is being submitted to the database by `query.Max();`?

Comment: When you hover your mouse over the `var` next to `query` - what is its **type**?

Comment: How about trying this query `select top 1 Id from Messages order by Id Desc` in linq you `Context.Messages.Take(1).OrderByDescending(y=>y.Id)`;

Comment: @Eldho Actually the "orderby then take first" way of doing it is fast. I edited my original post, and have a warning only with the Max function. No problem with the orderby function which is a great alternative.

Comment: Interesting. You should not need to cast the ID to use `Max()`, and you definitely wouldn't want to cast it to a null-able value. methinks you've stumbled on a bug either in the adapter or EF Core. I've definitely seen no such behaviour from EF6. (When treading along the bleeding edge, the only certainty is you're going to get bloody. :) it's good that the work-around works. That warning would explain the performance hit you were taking as EF would be executing the statement prematurely to perform the Max. (which it certainly should not be)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first statement (`Select`) doesn't execute anything against the DB so it should be 0ms. The behaviour of statements like `Max()` will vary by Database adapter.

I would look to try:

```
var maxId = context.Messages.Max(m => m.Id);
```

and for comparison:

```
var message1 = context.Messages.Where(m => m.Id == context.Messages.Max(x => x.Id)).Single();
//vs
var message2 = context.Messages.FromSql("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) from messages)").Single();
```

If this is a "cold" test against a DbContext, I would also look to eliminate any warm-up time for the context on first run. I'd expect that would have been satisfied by the initial `Select` call, though the 0ms time would be suspicious unless something touched the DbContext before that call. To be sure:

```
var warmup = context.Messages.First();

//start timing here...
var maxId = context.Messages.Select(m => m.Id).Max();
maxId = context.Messages.Max(m => m.Id);

var message1 = context.Messages.Where(m => m.Id = context.Messages.Max(x => x.Id)).Single();
//vs
var message2 = context.Messages.FromSql("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) from messages)").Single();
```

From there, if there is a difference between the last 2 calls, I would hook up a profiler (if possible) and inspect the queries sent to the database. The EF query (message1) should differ primarily by that it will explicitly list the columns in the entity rather than `SELECT *`.

Edit: Ok, after a bit of experimentation with this against a large, manufactured table of 3 million records.. Some interesting results. (Run against SQL Server)

```
var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var query = context.Messages.Select(x => x.MessageId).Max();
stopWatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms. (Select.Max)" + "  " + query);
stopWatch.Restart();

query = context.Messages.Select(x => x.MessageId).Max(x=>x);
stopWatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms. (Select.Max(x=>))" + "  " + query);
stopWatch.Restart();

query = context.Messages.Max(x => x.MessageId);
stopWatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms. (Max(x=>))" + "  " + query);
stopWatch.Restart();

var result = context.Messages.Where(x => x.MessageId == context.Messages.Max(y => y.MessageId)).Single();
stopWatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms. (get by Max(x=>))"  + "  " + result.MessageId);
```

This netted results of:

```
257ms. (Select.Max)  3000000
4ms. (Select.Max(x=>))  3000000
3ms. (Max(x=>))  3000000
210ms. (get by Max(x=>))  3000000
```

The interesting result was:
.Select(x => x.MessageId).Max();
vs.
.Select(x => x.MessageId).Max(x => x);

The first took 257ms while the second was 4ms. 
However, reversing the queries saw the results being the same. The .Select().Max(x => x) flavour took the 257ms, while Select.Max() took 4 ms.

Running a profiler against the runs showed that all queries didn't even register an execution cost. 0ms each. So this time was being taken by EF internally.

What is curious is that the first three scenarios to get the max ID run exactly the same SQL..

```
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        MAX([Extent1].[MessageId]) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Messages] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
go
```

Separating the runs into separate DbContext instances did not have an immediate impact. Again the first run took a performance hit, with the subsequent runs.

By moving the query that selects the entity with the criteria using Max() to be the first query run yielded still more interesting results:

```
486ms. (get by Max(x=>))  3000000
50ms. (Max(x=>))  3000000
14ms. (Select.Max(x=>))  3000000
2ms. (Select.Max)  3000000
```

It was notably slower running it first, but the following queries were fast-ish with no 200ms runs, but not as "fast" individually.

Diving a bit deeper I tried:
`.OrderByDescending(x => x.MessageId).Select(x => x.MessageId).Take(1).Single()`

Executed first it had an execution time of 100ms as opposed to the 230+ms for the `.Max()` while when executed after a `Max()` the execution time was ~50ms.

On a long-shot, turning off lazy loading and proxy creation had no effect. Using `.AsNoTracking()` also had little to no impact on the query times.

While this difference in execution time is not really explainable given the SQL being run is identical, and query execution times do not explain any difference, it is clear that EF is doing something beyond the warm-up behind the scenes. In my test case against SQL Server, the execution time differences are noticeable but not enough to explain what is being seen in SQLite. I suspect something with the SQLite adapter may be introducing a much more expensive query so I would be investigating profiling options to confirm what queries are being executed.

Comment: 1) Yes, I noticed the "warm-up" on first run, my results above are on second run. 
2) `maxId` takes 3-4 seconds. 
3) `message2` still takes 1ms. 
4) `message1` takes very long. I had to stop after 2 minutes or so (I replaced `m => m.Id = context...` with `m => m.Id == context...` because I think that's what you meant). 

5) I'll try the profiler tomorrow, thank you for your help!

Comment: Ok, thanks, I corrected the typo. That is a curious scenario. I'd be quite suspicious of the EF adapter since that almost seems as if it wants to fetch back all rows to perform the max in memory.

Comment: I've run a test scenario using SQL Server and got some interesting results. I've updated my answer with the results I was seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the results. I think I found the problem when profiling, I edited my original post. But still can't fix it. The "OrderBy then take first" statement is faster than Max() since I don't have this warning.

Answer (score -2):

"Trying to figure out why the LINQ Max function is actually way slower than the raw SQL query."

The LINQ functions by default will retreive the *entire table*, to then do processing in the Client. You added a network load equal to 1 result set, times the number of rows in the table. The Retrieval from the Disk, Network Transmission and memory allocation will be your bottlenecks here.

The SQL will do the processing in the DB. It has stuff like Indexes to speed up the process. So it might not even need to query the Disk. Maybe it even has the previous max cached. And then only transmit the *one* value. However fast the DBMS can do that processing will be the bottleneck. And I have no doubt that it is fast. DB's are designed for two things:

1. Realiability
2. Speed

My general advice is:

- If you need to do any filtering, sorting our paging (including cardinal operators like MAX) - *always* do it in the DBMS. Always retrieve as few values as possible from the DB.
- But also do not spam single request to the DB. There is overhead in every query and if you can get the same result with one

Comment: "The LINQ functions by default will retreive the entire table, to then do processing in the Client." This is not true. Such would be the case if the query did something like `.Select(x => x.Id).ToList().Max()`, where `ToList()` would materialize the query resulting in the `Max()` running Linq2Object rather than Linq2EF. Linq expressions in Linq2EF get compiled down into SQL. That said, there may be a bug/limitation in the SQLite adapter that is resulting in an in-memory operation.

Comment: @StevePy I said "by default", indicating that there can be exceptions. An optimisation to pass it down to SQL (LINQ to SQL?) might exist, but as you said your self it might not be working. The OP asumed it was working, so I pointed out the asumption was not a good one. And I am unsure why people would even asume it was working that way - with SQL we know it is working that way. LINQ is just a imitation of SQL. Learning LINQ also teaches SQL concepts. So if you got a DB Datasource anyway, just use the SQL.

Comment: I disagree, the whole purpose of an ORM is to convert OO code to SQL/DB language. EF's Linq support by design performs this translation to the extent that if you try any Linq operation that is not supported by EF then it will raise an exception, not default to an in-memory. Developers facing this limitation may purposefully force the expression to Linq2Object. I stated it may be possible that there is a limitation or bug in the SQLite adapter for EF since it's ultimately responsible for converting the Linq operation to SQL.